# Samsung Galaxy S7 is saving MMS photos to downloads folder instead of photos folder

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s7, mms

Samsung Galaxy S7 started saving MMS photos to the `downloads` folder instead of the `photos` folder.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you change or update your SMS/MMS app?

Comment: Not that I know of, but Samsung updates things automatically.

Comment: You're welcome.  As a first step, perhaps check the SMS/MMS app to see if it has any new settings that were introduced.  Also, is the `photos` folder where the images previously got filed within the `DCIM` folder?

Comment: Sorry you have a phone novice here. I just use them but don't know the terminology well at all. what is the DCIM and how do I tell? Photos shows up on my apps screen. The text app is whatever it came with - messaging?

Comment: Couldn't find any settings in "Messages" that might relate to default for saving attachments. Got to leave for a dinner thing. I'll have to catch up later today or tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: No problem.  When you receive a photo via "text", it is called an MMS message.  An app on your phone will automatically respond when such an message is received.  That app will usually determine where the image is stored.  Most likely, a new app was installed or an existing app was updated that changed the storage location.  Determining the app and seeing if has adjustable settings will likely be key to resolving the issue.  If there is not such option, there are automation apps that can do this for you, but they do take some work to get configured.  Enjoy your meal!

Comment: Thank you for the help. The only app I can find is just "Messages." I'll see what I can do about finding some options that aren't there at first glance.  Best wishes.

Comment: You're welcome.  Take care.